# Convert() SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have this query on SQL Server, the goal of this query is to set the milliseconds to 000, for instance,

Before this Query: 2017-06-01 11:53:00.123 
After: 2017-06-01 11:53:00.000

```
UPDATE table1 
  SET ValidFrom = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(19), ValidFrom, 126)) 
WHERE ValidFrom IS NOT NULL;
```

ValidFrom is a column on the database that it is a datetime.

There is a Convert command on Oracle but it doesn't work with Datetime.

How can I translate this to Oracle?

Comment: You will need to explain what that expression does - not everyone that knows Oracle knows what `convert()` does or what that 126 is supposed to do. There is also no `datetime` data type in Oracle. You are probably looking for `timestamp`

Comment: 1º It is a query to remove the milliseconds, 
Before this Query: 2017-06-01 11:53:00.123
After: 2017-06-01 11:53:00.000. 2º 126 is a optional parameter in convert method to say the type of datetime that it has to convert (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm)

Comment: @CMorillo Why do you want to remove milliseconds?

Comment: The name `ValidFrom` is typically used in Temporal Tables (unrelated to Temporary Tables, btw) - **if this is a Temporal Table then you should not be modifying `ValidFrom` or `ValidTo` at all** (in fact I don't think you even _can_ as SQL Server will block the write).

Comment: What version of Oracle Database are you using?

Comment: @Dai this is not a temporal table, thank you for your advice but I have to modify it because the milliseconds are killing my application

Comment: @Dai I am using Oracle Client 19c

Comment: @CMorillo "milliseconds are killing my application" - uhm, **what?** - that indicates that _something else_ is the problem, not your database.

Comment: "Oracle Client 19c" - that's the **client** version - I'm asking what **server version** you're using.

Comment: @Dai I know that problem is not in the database, but if I modify the database will be quicker than fix the real problem. and to be honest, I don't need milliseconds, it is not an important information

Comment: This does not directly address your question, but delving into a conversion you may benefit taking a look at [Migrate your mindset too](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Converting any strongly-typed `date`, `datetime`, `datetimeoffset`, etc column to `char`/`varchar` is a code-smell and a strong hint that you're doing something wrong because you should never need to format-dates to perform date/time processing in SQL.
- Oracle doesn't have a `datetime` type like SQL Server does, instead it has a `timestamp` type (which has absolutely nothing to do with SQL Server's own `timestamp` type which is an alias for `rowversion` but I digress).
- Oracle's `timestamp` type is parameterised to specify the amount of precision for sub-second resolution - so simply `CAST`ing your value to `timestamp(0)` will effectively zero-out the milliseconds component.
- You can also use the `EXTRACT` function to obtain the integer value (`0-999`) of the milliseconds component of a `timestamp` value.

```
UPDATE
    table
SET
    ValidFrom = CAST( ValidFrom AS timestamp(0) )
WHERE
    ValidFrom IS NOT NULL
```

---

[Here's a working demo in SQLFiddle, using Oracle 11g R2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29578/11):

**Build Schema Script:**

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (
    ValidFrom timestamp(7) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO testTable ( ValidFrom )
WITH v AS ( 
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '1997-01-08 11:11:11.111' AS ts FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '1997-02-09 12:22:22.222' AS ts FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '1997-03-10 13:33:33.333' AS ts FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT TIMESTAMP '1997-04-11 14:44:44.444' AS ts FROM dual
) 
SELECT ts FROM v
```

**Query script:**

```
SELECT
  ValidFrom,
  CAST( ValidFrom AS timestamp(0) ) AS ValidFrom_withoutMilliseconds,
  ( ValidFrom - CAST( ValidFrom AS timestamp(0) ) ) AS diff
FROM
  testTable

//

UPDATE
    testTable
SET
    ValidFrom = CAST( ValidFrom AS timestamp(0) )
WHERE
    ValidFrom IS NOT NULL

//

SELECT
  ValidFrom,
  CAST( ValidFrom AS timestamp(0) ) AS ValidFrom_withoutMilliseconds,
  ( ValidFrom - CAST( ValidFrom AS timestamp(0) ) ) AS diff
FROM
  testTable
```

- Today I learned that `//` is the query separator, which is separate from the "query terminator" in Oracle.
- To my surprise, Oracle Database **still** doesn't support milliseconds with `EXTRACT`, fortunately that isn't necessary for this query.

Comment: this query won't work because you are removing the milliseconds and I don't want to remove them, I want to change its value to .000

Comment: @CMorillo Have you tried my query or not?

Comment: @CMorillo It should work because while there is an explicit _narrowing_ cast from `timestamp(n)` to `timestamp(0)` (which will remove the millisecond values), observe that the `SET ValidFrom = ` will invoke an **implicit cast** back to the column's `timestamp(n)` type which will cause the milliseconds component to be zeroed, the same way that casting a `date` value to a `datetime` or `timestamp` value will cause the hours, minutes, and seconds components to be zeroed out.

Comment: I tried your query and I got an error: "missing Keyword". I think there is something wrong in the CAST command

Comment: @CMorillo I've updated my answer. It just needed `AS` instead of `,`.

Comment: @CMorillo I stress that **you still haven't said what exactly version** of Oracle Database Server you're running - because not all versions support `EXTRACT( , MILLISECOND )`.

Comment: "*Today I learned that // is the query separator*" - that's just SQLFiddle and has nothing to do with Oracle itself. I prefer https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18 over SQLFiddle anyway